# Sytnax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Tags: java, string, methods, variable-assignment

I'm doing an assignment in Computer Science, and I'm getting a couple of errors. I had to upload the code because I couldn't get it to work on Stackoverflow. Here's the link: http://txt.do/tqmh

Here are the errors:

```
16 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 15]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 15]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 32]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 32]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 57]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 57]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 83]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 83]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 112]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 112]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 137]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 137]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 161]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 161]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 184]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\Om\Desktop\CYOA_Om_Malhar.java  [line: 184]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
```

Please help!

Comment: The same way you got the errors to show up is how you get code to show up.

Comment: You should really start with a basic Java tutorial. You can't just have method invocations in the middle of a class body.

Comment: I'm actually learning Java. I'm in Grade 11. And according to the teacher, this is how we have to do the assignment.

Comment: The first thing I saw was methods being defined inside of the main() method. This is fundamentally wrong. If your teacher told you to do it like this, tell him/her to come talk to us.

Comment: @Takendarkk How would I go on to solve this?

Comment: I'm not going to correct all the code (sorry I'm on a phone) but you can go through it keeping in mind some of the java basics like 1) main method starts the program and is where you will call methods from mostly (for example call `Introduction()` from inside main()) 2) You can't define methods inside of methods.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Takendarkk! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do but this code should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CYOA_Om_Malhar 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "";
        Introduction();

        //Instructions
        System.out.println("Please type 'A' or 'B' to choose an option: ");
        while(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B") ){
            choice = in.nextLine();
        }

        page1(choice);
        page2(choice);
        page3(choice);
        page4(choice);
        page5(choice);
        page6(choice);
        page7();


    }
    public static void Introduction()
    {
        System.out.println("You are walking home one night after being fired from your job. "); 
        System.out.println("You are late on your rent, and you have no money. ");
        System.out.println("As you are walking by, you see a black object out of the corner of your eye. ");
        System.out.println("You reach over to pick it up, and you realize that it's a wallet full of cash. ");
        System.out.println("You take it home to your rat infested apartment. ");
        System.out.println("You then start counting the money as soon as you sit on the squeaky chair of yours. ");
        System.out.println("You get surprised as you notice that the wallet has $10,000. What do you do?");
    }

    //Page 1
    public static int page1(String choice)
    {
        System.out.println("A. Take the wallet to the police station. ");
        System.out.println("B. Use the money to rent a new condo near Lakeshore Blvd., and lease a new BMW X6. ");


        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            System.out.println("Great decision. ");
            return 2;
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            System.out.println("You're disonest. Start over. :(");
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again. ");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //Page 2
    public static int page2(String choice)
    {
        System.out.println("Now, all you have to do is find a way to get to the police station - which is on the other side of the town. ");
        System.out.println("How do you get there? ");
        System.out.println("A. Hitchhike! Stand by the side of the road, and wait for a car to pass by. ");
        System.out.println("B. Borrow $10 from your Aunt May. ");

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            System.out.println("You're standing there on the side of the road, and no cars are passing by. Try again. ");
            return -1;
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            System.out.println("Rejoice! Your aunt agrees to give you $10!");
            return 3;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again. ");
            return -2;
        }
    }
    //Page 3
    public static int page3(String choice)
    {
        System.out.println("You hear Macklemore's 'Thrift Shop' playing in the background. For some odd reason, you feel rich today. ");
        System.out.println("As you're walking your jolly way, you see a beggar on the street. You notice his pale skin, and that unpleasant smell he carries around with him. ");
        System.out.println("You stop near him, and he asks you for $5, and says that he hasn't eaten any food for the part 2 days. ");
        System.out.println("What do you do?");
        System.out.println("A. Give $5 to the beggar. ");
        System.out.println("B. Act as if you're not listening to him, and walk away. ");

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            System.out.println("Great choice!");
            return 4;
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            System.out.println("You're very shelfish. Try again. ");
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again. ");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    //Page 4
    public static int page4(String choice)
    {
        System.out.println("You finally reach the bus stop. ");
        System.out.println("Upon looking at the bus timings, you realize that you've missed the last bus for the night. ");
        System.out.println("What do you do? ");
        System.out.println("A. Spend the night at the hotel. ");
        System.out.println("B. Wait for the bus for a couple of hours. ");


        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            System.out.println("Great choice!");
            return 6;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again. ");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    public static int page5(String choice)
    {
        System.out.println("Hotel, huh? You walk to the hotel.");
        System.out.println("You go to the counter, and the receptionist tells you that the hotel is full. ");
        System.out.println("What do you do?");
        System.out.println("A. Go back in time.");
        System.out.println("B. Go back to the bus stop and wait there for a couple of hours.");


        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            return 6;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again.");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    public static int page6(String choice)
    {
        System.out.println("2.78 HOURS LATER. ");
        System.out.println("It's almost dawn. You finally see a bus coming right at you. ");
        System.out.println("You get in the bus. Everything seems normal. UNTIL... ");
        System.out.println("A man climbs on the bus. He has a black cloth wrapped around his face. He takes a look at everyone in the bus through two holes in the cloth. ");
        System.out.println("He then asks everyone for money, jewelry, and watches. ");
        System.out.println("What do you do?");
        System.out.println("A. Don't give the cash to the thug. ");
        System.out.println("B. Give the cash to the thug. ");


        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            return 7;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again.");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    public static void page7()
    {
        System.out.println("As you are handing the cash to the thug, you hear sirens in the near distant.");
        System.out.println("The thug RUNS before he could take the cash. You feel very relieved. ");
        System.out.println("You FINALLY approach the police station.");
        System.out.println("You give the wallet to the police, and they thank you for your honesty. ");
        System.out.println("TWO DAYS LATER.");
        System.out.println("A knock on the door. It's Bill Gates! He thanked you for returning the wallet, and writes you a check for $100,000! ");
        System.out.println("An hour later, another knock at the door. It's the beggar. He won a lottery with the $5 that you gave him. ");
        System.out.println("He writes you a check for $50,000! :D");
        System.out.println("You then buy a brand spanking new BMW X8, and a condo at Lakeshore Blvd.!");
        System.out.println("And then everyone lived happily ever after. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Although it crashes after the first input, it still gives me an idea as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What  do you put the first time?

Comment: I apologize for the extra late comment. It crashes regardless of what I enter, the program still crashes. My input in this case would be A or B.

Comment: Could you give me the type of Exception. Or past just the first line of error message

Answer (score 0):

As has been posted you have static methods inside a main method - which is fundamentally wrong. You can not have a method inside a method - unless its inside anonymous class (but lets not get into this). So to start you off remove all methods from `main(String[] args).`

So for example you should have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    page1();
    page2();
    page3();
}
// this is now outside of your main method but inside your class 
public static void page1() {

}
public static void page2() {

} 
//etc.
```

Also if you want to pass argument to a method - and i can see you will need to do that for your if statements, you can do so by doing i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this is just example..!!

    String letter = "A";
    page1(letter);

    // what the above code will do, is pass a letter "A" as an argument to this "page1"
    // method and as a result you will be able to use this letter inside the method

}
public static void page1(String letter) {
    System.out.println(letter); // this will print letter "A"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me better understand the use of string methods.